# What are the python version of the MATLAB's imgaborfilt and imgaussfilt functions?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Was trying to implement the task [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/texture-segmentation-using-gabor-filters.html) in python. I needed to perform Garbor filtering on a gray scale image and then Gaussian filtering on the garbor filtered image. While observing the result of the Python code and MATLAB code, I discovered they were entirely different.

In python there are functions cv2.filter2D  cv2.GaussianBlur for Garbor and Gaussian filtering just as MATLAB has imgaborfilt and imgaussfilt. Using the python functions as shown in the code snippet returns a matrix of just 0s and 1s, while MATLAB returns a matrix of floating point numbers.

```py
def garbor_filters(wavelength, orientation):
  ksize = 39
  kern = cv2.getGaborKernel(ksize=(ksize, ksize), sigma = 0.5, theta=orientation, lambd=wavelength, gamma=math.sqrt(2), psi=0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)
  return kern


def compute_garbor(img, filter):
 #filter: kernel obtained from the method above 
 filtered_img = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, filter)
 return filtered_img

def getgaussianFiltrdImg(imageGarbors, filters):
  #filters: a tuple of wavelength and orientation  
  sigma = 0.5*filters[0]; #get wavelength
  K = 3;
  filtersize=2*math.ceil(2*K*sigma)+1
  gau_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(imageGarbors, (filtersize,filtersize), K*sigma)
  return gau_img


# call the methods
realimage = cv2.imread('kobi.png')
realimage = cv2.cvtColor(realimage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = rescale(realimage, 0.25, anti_aliasing=False)

imageGarbors=getImageGabor(img, (2.82,0))
imageGauss=getgaussianFiltrdImg(imageGarbors, (2.82,0))
```

Python returns just 0s and 1s in the matrices while MATLAB returns continues values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your call to `cv2.filter2D`, you explicitly tell it to return result as 8 bit unsigned integers. The result of `cv2.GaussianBlur` has the same datatype as the input. You're feeding it 8bit unsigned integers, so you get 8bit unsigned integers out as well.

Comment: Oh! That's true. Which of the depth do I use then CV_16S/CV_32F/CV_64F? Can you also confirm if my getgaussianFiltrdImg looks correct?

Comment: Either `32F` or `64F`, those are the two floating point types. Choose which precision is sufficient.